# How to make XML DOCTYPE have single quotes instead of double quotes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using an .xsl file to transform an XML file that FileMaker Pro exports into another XML file that is formatted to the PBCore 2.0 schema. My organization needs to be able to open the output XML file in chrome as part of the workflow. Everything seems to be working fine, except for the issue where the header of the output file reads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

It seems that the first one, with the double quotes, will NOT open in chrome, whereas the second one will open in chrome. Is there anywhere in xsl document I can specify that this line use single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: Can you offer evidence for your claim that Chrome cares which quotes? In any case, unless you tell us what XSLT you are using, we can't possibly come up with a way to control the quotes.

Comment: The only evidence I have is that the files won't open in chrome with double quotes and will open in chrome with single quotes. I realize I may be trying to fix the wrong problem, but that simple change allows me to open the documents in chrome. I've also noticed that if I transform the XML files with `xsltproc` the files wont open, but if I copy/paste the output of the debug window in oXygen into a new xml file it will open in chrome. Needless to say, I'm a but confused.

Comment: So I just realized that either the single-quotes or double-quotes will open in chrome, given that I open the XML file in TextWrangler and resave it. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I'd check for a Unicode BOM character's absence or presence.

Answer (score 0):

The first one most certainly will open in chrome, you've got a different problem.

Now, you could use `<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />` to leave it out entirely (that declaration hits the defaults, so its being absent won't matter).

You could even do that and then use some nasty unescaped-output to write in one with single-quotes.

But still, the form with `"` will most certainly open in chrome, so you're solving the wrong problem.